# Trouble importing modules from different dir

Tags: python-2.7, import, module

I thought I have figured out importing modules in Python but it seems I'm still lacking in this area. I cannot figure out why this is not working. This is my structure:

```
|__bin/
    |__ __init__.py
    |__ main.py
|__modules/
     |__ __init__.py
     |__ module1.py
     |__ module2.py
|__tests/
     |__ __init__.py
     |__ test_module1.py
```

I thought that by adding `__init__.py` the folder becomes a package. Because I try to do this in my `main.py` file:

```
from modules.module1 import func1
```

`func1` is a simple function in `module1.py`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory *containing* `modules` must be listed in `sys.path` in order for Python to import the `modules` package. One way to add that directory to `sys.path` is to add it your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: What is strange is that I have `/tests` folder where I run tests from. Those tests use the same import method and it works by running `nosetests` from `/tests` directory.

Comment: I've tried adding `modules/` to my `PYTHONPATH` variable but it still says that `No module named modules`

Comment: Yes you were right, I needed to add `PYTHONPATH`. My problem was that my project directory was not added in `PYTHONPATH` in my `.bash-profile` file so I added it in there, restarted terminal and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [The nose docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html) say, "When nose imports a module, it adds that module’s directory to sys.path". This might be why you were seeing different behavior when running `nosetests`.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was my `PYTHONPATH` variable wasn't in my `.bash_profile` file (I'm on a Mac). Putting `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Path/To/My/Project` and restarting terminal did the trick.

The reason why I was confused was because `nose.tools` module was working flawlessly and could reach `modules/` directory with no problem. As @unutbu said in my comments, this is a feature of `nose`, it says that [in their documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html).

Creating `__init__.py` file in dir is not enough, you must make sure Python can read the directory where your project is stored (see above).